# python using pickled objects with sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, pickle

I have a large object that is fairly dynamic that I want to serialize and store in my sqlite database.  Using the pickle module, I made it into a string but found I had to do a string replace on it to change the single quotes out in order to store it to the db.  When I take it out, I just undo that.  I am new to using pickle and sqlite and this at least works, but is this really the right way to go about it or is there a correct way to handle this that I am not seeing?

```
menu = pickle.dumps(menuOb)
menu = menu.replace("'", "''")
#sql statement stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't replace any characters, just insert with a SQL parameter:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (?, ?)', (id, pickle.dumps(menuOb))
```

SQL parameters take care of correct quoting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am definitely a SQL noob.  What I was doing just seemed silly and this makes a lot more sense.